# SSAS - Return dates where no data exists

Tags: ssas

How, in SQL Server Analysis Services, how can I return rows of data for dates where no data exists?  In this instance, ideally, I'd want to return the value of 0.  In plain SQL, I would do this with a CTE.  However, I'm still figuring out SSAS.

[image]

Comment: What is your real client tool? I'm assuming you won't put the SSMS cube browser in users' hands as a real client tool.

Comment: Is null or blank acceptable or is a zero required?

Comment: The client tool will likely be Excel.  Null or blank might be acceptable, but for charting purposes, I figured a 0 would display better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on your PivotTable and choose PivotTable Options. Select the tab labeled "Display". There is an option called "Show items with no data in rows". Put a check mark by that one.

If you prefer zero then on the Layout & Format tab of that same dialog set "For empty cells show" to 0.