# Display empty cells in cubes ssas

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008

[image]

How to display all request no and if for a request no there is no Montant so I need to display null

[image]

Comment: What's the real client tool users will be using to connect to the cube? I assume it won't be SSMS and the answer differs by client tool.

Comment: @GregGalloway client acceess with excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35641973/5070440). It is just an Excel PivotTable option to show rows with no data.